# asp.net drop down list validation with CompareValidator?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to validate two dropdownlists on an .aspx page. One list contains destinations while the other contains number of days (1 day to 14 days). I'm trying to make it such that a certain destination is only available for certain day lengths. For example, I want to make it such that no less than 7 day options are available for Mexico. If the user selects Mexico as their destination from the list and chooses any day option less than seven days, an error will pop up saying that "This destination only has options for 7 days and above."

Can I use the CompareValidator to do this? If so, how?

Comment: Looks like you want to make the number of days dependent on the location selected. Why not filter and load the number of days dropdown in the selected index changed event of the location dropdown?

Comment: Because I need to show some sort of error message if something isn't done right or formatted correctly. Personally, I'd try doing something like that as well, but following instructions and all that...